# Java save CMYK image to file

Tags: java, image, file, jai, cmyk

I'm trying to create image in CMYK Colorspace and after working with it, for example, painting lines etc., save it to file. Unfortunately, there isn't a lot of information in the internet about CMYK in java. I have found only an article http://carback.us/rick/blog/?p=58. But there the Image is being saved to Pdf, using iText library. But I need it to be savet to png or jpeg file. Here is the code:

```
public BufferedImage createCMYKBufferedImage(double l_width, double l_height) {
    ColorSpace colorSpace = SimpleCMYKColorSpace.getInstance();
    ComponentColorModel l_ccm = new ComponentColorModel(colorSpace, false, false,
                            1, DataBuffer.TYPE_FLOAT);
    int[] l_bandoff = {0, 1, 2, 3}; //Index for each color (C, is index 0, etc)
    PixelInterleavedSampleModel l_sm = new PixelInterleavedSampleModel(
                               DataBuffer.TYPE_FLOAT,
                               (int)l_width, (int)l_height,
                                   4,(int)l_width*4, l_bandoff);
    WritableRaster l_raster = WritableRaster.createWritableRaster(l_sm,
            new Point(0, 0));
    return new BufferedImage(l_ccm, l_raster, false, null);
}
```

When I'm trying to save an image, i'm just calling

> ImageIO.write(image, format, file);

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

To write a BufferedImage as a Jpeg:

First, convert the BufferedImage to a Jpeg byte array.

```
import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.ImageFormatException;
import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGCodec;
import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGEncodeParam;
import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGImageDecoder;
import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGImageEncoder;

public static byte[] jpegToBytes(BufferedImage image) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(os);
    JPEGEncodeParam jparm = encoder.getDefaultJPEGEncodeParam(image);
    jparm.setQuality(1F, false);

    try {
        encoder.encode(image, jparm);
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        EclipseLogging.logError(RabidPhotoPlugin.getDefault(),
                RabidPhotoPlugin.PLUGIN_ID, e);
        return new byte[0];
    }
    return os.toByteArray();
}
```

Next, write the byte array to a file.

```
public static void writePhoto(byte[] photo) {
    try {
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream('file name');
        os.write(photo);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful, but image being produced is black. Any ideas?

Comment: @Vladimir: I pulled this code out of a working application.  Make a simple BufferedImage, and make sure you get a valid Jpeg from the simple BufferedImage.  Then add more BufferedImage code, a little at a time, until you get the image you want.

Answer (score -1):

It seems, you have a controversy in the question. Jpeg and PNG have RGB image format. For example, look 
http://forums.adobe.com/message/2704225. 
So, you have to put the source picture directly into png/jpeg or print CMYK to pdf. CMYK is a printing format, not a screen one.

Comment: Jpegs can use a CMYK colors space, and can be used for both screen and print.